# Keras fit_generator running very slowly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have a Keras Model declared with the following code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, input_shape=(settings["past_size"], len(indicators_used))))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(
    generator=batch_generator(train_x, train_y),
    steps_per_epoch=n_batches_per_epoch,
    epochs=settings["epochs"],
    workers=5,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    max_queue_size=10000)
```

I experimented with the `workers`, `use_multiprocessing` and the `max_queue_size` settings but to no avail. The input shape is `(100000, 500, 27)`.

The Batch Generator function looks like this:

```
def batch_generator(x, y):
    while True:
        for i in range(n_batches_per_epoch):
            x_train = []
            y_train = []
            for j in range(settings["past_size"] + settings["batch_size"] * i, settings["past_size"] + (settings["batch_size"] * (i + 1))):
                x_train.append(x.iloc[j - past_size:j].to_numpy())
                y_train.append(y.iloc[j].to_numpy())
            return_x, return_y = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
            yield return_x, return_y
```

Execution Times:

- Batch Size 256: `767ms/step`
- Batch Size 512: `1s/step`
- Batch Size 1024: `2s/step`

The problem I'm facing now is that the Keras training process is incredibly slow. One Epoch is taking approximately 45 minutes. I can't use `model.fit()` because the data is too large for the RAM.

My understanding of the batch_generator functionality was, that the function prepares batches and loads them on the GPU / TPU, but that doesn't seem to be the case. This Code runs in Google Colab with the TPU Runtime.

Comment: What batch size are you using? Did you increase it?

Comment: I'm using a batch size of 128. I also tried to increase it. It got a bit faster but not that much.

Comment: Please add numbers, not subjective evaluations like "fast but not that much". 45 minutes per epoch could be normal for your hardware and model, depending on what is being the bottleneck.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I edited the question and added the execution times per step for the different batch_sizes I tried.

Comment: I validated, that the queue for batches is always full. So a too slow batch generation or something similar cannot be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Google colab environment, you need to explicitly convert the model to a TPU compatible version. This was my mistake when I worked with Google Colab the last time.

```
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
    tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

`tpu_model` has the same interface as `model`.

Guide:
https://medium.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-on-tpus-on-colab-674367932aa0

Unfortunately, this doesn´t seem to work with the `Sequential` api.